# check value if exist sqlite error insert

Tags: android

i have a method to insert data and check when code is exists or not

if exist dont create insert and if not exists will create insert

but when i try to running the data cant insert to a database

here is my insert code

```
public void processAddA(DialogWrapper wrapper)
               {
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);

            values.put(DatabaseHelper.CODE, wrapper.getCode());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.ALAMAT, wrapper.getAlamat());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.BATAS, wrapper.getBatas());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.LAT, wrapper.getLat());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.LON, wrapper.getLon());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.LUAS, wrapper.getLuas());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.TANGGAL_AWAL, wrapper.getTglA());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.TANGGAL_AKHIR, wrapper.getTglB());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.USER_ID, wrapper.getUser());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.SENT, "0");

                  open();
                  //check if value exist or not.
                  Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM petak_tetap where code='"
                            + wrapper.getCode() + "'", null);
                  if(c == null)
                  {
                  //doesn't exists therefore insert record.
                      database.insert("petak_tetap", DatabaseHelper.ALAMAT,
                                values);
                  }
                  close();
               }
```

how to fix that?

Comment: are u getting any error? plz also use log for check Select query value and if statement is executing or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this condition it will work

```
if (c!=null && c.getCount()==0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all c is never null you should use

`if (!c.moveToFirst())`

But it is a lot easier if you declare your code column to be `UNIQUE` and then use `insertWithOnConflict` with `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE` as the last param.